# Log4net logging details not stored in the database in few occasions

Tags: .net, log4net

I am logging the Web Api request and response details in Database using Log4net. When i am running the application for the first time in Visual Studio, it not logging the details. After debugging the corresponding the Logging code, the Log4Net start logging the informations. I just wonder why it is happening.

I have changed the buffer size to 1 and Level Value to All as well. I cant find the root cause. Can anyone experienced wild behaviour like this.

Answer (score 0):

Log4net only starts logging when XmlConfigurator.Configure is called. Make sure you do this as one of the first things when you application starts. If it keeps happening, you can add [internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) to see if you have any exception in the appenders.

Comment: Hi Peter,  I have already added log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() in WebApiConfig file. My problem is Log.Info is working in few scenarios and not logging in few scenarios